# How do I instantiate Interfaces with Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, hardhat

I am trying to Approve a transaction and I need the IERC20 interface from OpenZeppelin to do so. How do I import it into Hardhat with Javascript.

I tried using getContractFactory() but I keep getting a

```
     HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "../contracts/IERC20.sol" not found.
```

If I try to import it from the json file like:

```
const { IERC20 } =require("../artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol/IERC20.json");
```

I get `TypeError: IERC20 is not a function` errors when trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

IERC20Artifact = await hre.artifacts.readArtifact("contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol:IERC20");
```